# Expected ":" pylance [ln3 , Col 14] error

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python . i am getting this error in python . please tell me the logic behind this error .

```
def sequence (n):
    while n  ! == 1:
        print(n)
        if n%2 == 0:
            n = n/2 
        else:
         n=n*3+1
```

please tell me the logic behind this error

Comment: check the indentation of the line `n=n*3+1`. Indentation is VERY IMPORTANT in python

Comment: **1.** `while n != 1:` you had `! ==` Python does not have strict comparison like JS and there should be no space.  PS: It's recommended that you follow consistent indentation space across all the blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# declaring a function that takes a value n as a parameter
def sequence (n):
   # checking if n is not equal to 1, if yes moving into the loop
   while n != 1: # n ! == 1 will give error, this is not the correct syntax to compare values in python
      # printing the value
      print(n)
      # if n is an even number then diving n by 2 ( integer division )
      if n%2 == 0:
         n = n//2 
      # if n is not even then using the following formula
      else:
         n = n*3 + 1 
# calling the function to execute the operation that we wrote before
sequence(10)
```

Gives the following output:

```
10
5
16
8
4
2
```

I recommend you to learn python by following a YouTube video first and then get along with the syntax as you go through. Best of luck!